# Best practice to maintain high charge count

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a MacBook Pro, always plugged, I put it to sleep during the night. Is  that the best thing to do if I want to maintain a high number of remaining charges, while also keeping a healthy battery?

Or should I turn it off at night instead of sleep, plug it off, or something else?

Comment: You should read what [Apple says about maximizing battery performance](https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/#macbook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apple has a useful page with some tips on how to keep your battery healthy right here: [Apple battery tips](https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/)
They also recommend discharging the battery about once a month.
I don't think sleeping instead of powering off makes that much of a difference.